# R: Getting note about using zip::zipr() instead of zip::zip() - is it cause for concern?

Tags: r, openxlsx

When I use `write.xlsx` from `library(xlsx)`, the following appears in the console:

```
Note: zip::zip() is deprecated, please use zip::zipr() instead
```

What does this mean? How important is it that I use `zip::zipr()`, and if it is important, how do I go about fixing that?

My code looks like this:

```
hs <- createStyle(textDecoration = "BOLD")

mwb <- write.xlsx(
list(a, b, c), 
"./myfile.xlsx",
sheetName = c("Sheet A", "Sheet B", "Sheet C"),
col.names = TRUE,
ow.names = FALSE,
headerStyle = hs)
```

Comment: There's already [issue #454](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/454) for changing awalker89's [single use of `zip::zip`](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/blob/ead0038c59a227faa5c03f13aa7c6211f63dc9e0/R/WorkbookClass.R#L544).

Comment: Millie, I think you're probably "fine" for now relying on `openxlsx` with this warning: the [`zip.Rd`](https://github.com/r-lib/zip/blob/master/man/zip.Rd) does not seem to suggest a near-horizon for removal, so the warning should be okay to ignore. If it annoys you sufficiently, you might be able to silence it with `suppressMessages(write.xlsx(...))` (since it appears that [`zip` uses `simpleMessage`](https://github.com/r-lib/zip/blob/ef57e0e499b2e4539a909114753405ce769517d3/R/utils.R#L133) instead of `warning`), though that will be suppressing *all* messages in that call.

Comment: ... but be on the lookup for an updated version of `openxlsx`. it's great when it works ... until it doesn't. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can make this note disappear by loading your zip package first, because zipr function is in the new zip package and zip function has been disabled by the old zip package. 
library(zip)